# Wordpress images not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: wordpress, internet-explorer

The site i've been working on is using wordpress and the plugin Master Slider for a main slider on the site, [here is the site](http://www.dreamteam.gg), but some of the images do not work in Internet Explorer and I'm not sure why. The photos all work in every other browser i've tried. I've tried putting IE into compatibility mode and it didn't work, also trying to view the images via going directly to the url and that says that the url is not valid. I've never had this sort of problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Check the console output in IE:

```
SCRIPT5009: 'MasterSlider' is undefined
File: www.dreamteam.gg, Line: 251, Column: 5
```

IE also throws 3 warnings.

Firefox does not show any errors/warnings.

Comment: Ok thank you, but the other images like in the header aren't loading either

Comment: I'm not sure what other images you are referring to.  If you mean the 4000 pixel wide Dream Team image (http:///www.dreamteam.gg/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/dream-team-text-logo.png) you might want replace `http:///` with `http://` before you resize it.

Comment: It seems to be doing that for most of the photos, including the ones in the slider, would you have any idea why?

Comment: I'm sorry but without seeing the backend I wouldn't have a clue; I've never used that (or any) slider plugin.  I don't know where or how you specified the images.  Look at the slider setup options and verify the image URLS are correct.

Comment: Its weird because its happening with more than just this plugin, all of the plugins are doing this that have to do with generating image links and it is breaking the site in IE

Comment: The HTML is broken not IE, IE is just less forgiving with the malformed image URL. What happens when you view the WP media library in IE?

Comment: Non of the image links work when i do that, they are all broken

Comment: When you click an image in the medial library does the Edit Media screen appear?  If so, what does the File URL show?

Comment: It shows three backslashes, like this http:///www.dreamteam.gg/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IMG_6967.png

Comment: The problem might have occurred when the images were uploaded. Try exporting you data using WP Export and search the XML file for www.dreamteam.gg/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/IMG_6967.png; see if the `///` appears before 'www'.

Comment: Well that's a start.  Did you import data or manually add images to the library?  Also, when you go to Media -> Add New what address appears in your browser.  Try this in IE and another browser.  It would be easier to help you solve this by email or other direct contact.  Who receives the contact forms submitted at dreamteam.gg?

Comment: The URL problems on your site go beyond just images.  Looking at page source you'll see `<script type='text/javascript' src='http:///www.dreamteam.gg/wp-content/plugins/master-slider/public/assets/js/jquery.easing.min.js?ver=2.7.1'></script>`; that's most likely causing the 'MasterSlider' is undefined error that breaks the slider script.

I noticed someone asked you to check the WordPress and Site URL in your related question [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34972591/wordpress-adding-extra-slash-to-img-url-after-http]

What are the values for siteurl and home in the wp_options table.