# Wordpress adding extra slash to img url after http

Tags: wordpress

Wordpress is adding an extra slash after http for img urls on my [site](http://www.dreamteam.com) 
The image urls should look like a normal url but instead the image tags are like this:
http:///www.dreamteam.gg/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/crowd.jpg
notice the extra slash after http:
Not sure what would be causing this because these are links are not added by me, they are being made by three separate plugins and they all do this. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: What are the WordPress Address (URL) and Site Address (URL) under WP General Settings?

Comment: They are the normal http://www.dreamteam.gg for both, only two backslashes not three

Comment: what are those plug-ins?

Comment: Master slider and Add Posts to Pages

Comment: Viewing the images in the wordpress gallery all of the images have three backslashes

Comment: hmm I have installed your plugins but can not see any problem with urls.

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find out what initially caused this issue but i put this script in the footer and it fixed all my image src links.

```
$('img').attr('src',function(i,e){
  return e.replace("http:///w","http://w");
})
```

Make sure you are importing jQuery into your page or this won't work

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem.  The root cause of the the extra slash should be fixed.  Other links and external JS and CSS URLs still have `///` in the HTML source.

Comment: It doesn't solve the issue, but it makes the images display in IE and that was the big issue. Where are you seeing the other links with `///`?

Comment: View the source code in IE (or any other browser).  Search for `///` - you'll see quite a number of occurrences.  If it was my site I'd want to fix the problem; it's hard to say what other issues this could create in the long run.  But it's your site - enjoy.

BTW - I'm not seeing your slider images in IE11.

Comment: Yeah im not sure why that is, i've fixed the image links for it and made sure the js was being imported but it still doesn't show the images